# Materializecss with django cms for a website

Tags: django, materialize

I am using materializecss framework to create navigation in djangocms. I am unable to get the functionality so the dropdown and collapsible work correctly. Right now dropdown only shows one sub-menu, while collapsible wasn't working so I have put that on hold. Following is my menu.html code:

```
{% load i18n menu_tags cache %}
{% for child in children %}
<li class="child{% if child.selected %} active{% endif %}
{% if child.children %} dropdown{% endif %}">
{% if child.children %}
<a href="#" class="dropdown-button" data-activates="dropdown3">{{ child.get_menu_title }}
    <i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a>
<ul class="dropdown-content">
    {% show_menu from_level to_level extra_inactive extra_active template "" "" child %}
</ul>
{% else %}
   <a href="{{ child.attr.redirect_url|default:child.get_absolute_url }}">{{ child.get_menu_title }}</a>
{% endif %}
</li>
{% if class and forloop.last and not forloop.parentloop %}{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

And following is my base.html call on menu.html:

```
<ul id="dropdown3" class="dropdown-content">
{% show_sub_menu 1  %}
</ul>
<nav>
<div class="nav-wrapper">
 <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
 <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
     {% show_menu 0 100 100 100 "menu.html" %}
 </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

The drop down functionality I need to accomplish is in the following, but I want it done so I don't have to worry about ids:

I posted the link because it showed functionality as well, but here is the code:

```
<!-- Dropdown Structure -->
<ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
  <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
</ul>
<nav>
 <div class="nav-wrapper">
  <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
  <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
   <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
   <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
   <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
   <li><a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown1">Dropdown<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi. Sadly, I don't know anything about materializecss yet, but I think that doesn't really matter here. The templates only affect the mark-up, not the styles. So, can you add to your question what the *desired* markup should look like?

Comment: Well I am trying to create a mark-up so I am able to see drop-down menus + collapsible elements, which are otherwise not available in djangocms. Desired function should be in this link under "Navbar Dropdown Menu": http://materializecss.com/navbar.html

Comment: Dood, there's a lot of code at that link. Why not select the one you need and put it in your question so that people can help you?

Comment: posted it above. Thank you again.